# How to extract wireless access point properties in java?

Tags: java, networking, mac-address, wifi, access-point

I am trying to implement a method to detect **Rogue Access Points** in a Wireless LAN (IEEE 802.11) network.
What I need to do is to detect all the Access Points in the network along with their respective properties (**like MAC address, SSID, RSSID, etc**).
I need to know how to get these information using java. Some one told me I can use access point properties, but that didn't help much, as I am not able to find much about that (access point properties).
What I intend to do is capture the **beacon frames** from the network (just like *wireshark*) and use the parameters in the frame to extract those information.
I was successful to do so in **Python**, where I used the **Scapy Library** to capture the beacon frames.
Thanks.

Comment: Would help to tell us waht Operating System you're using.

Comment: I am using MS windows 7 64-bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn’t allows us to directly get that low level information. Therefore I think we have to run command line and run something like netsh commands inside java an extract that information. [This](https://notebookbft.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/wifi-information-extraction-java/) is how i did it in one of my projects.